# Subtracting two arrays of different dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What does this difference mean?

```
np.array([[1], [2]]) - np.array([[1, 2]])
```

It outputs

```
array([[ 0, -1],
       [ 1,  0]])
```

Comment: What do you mean by Resting?

Comment: I mean, subtract. It's a translation mistake, sorry.

Comment: You should edit the question title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whereas `np.array([[1], [2]])` is an array of dimension `(2,1)`, `np.array([[1, 2]])` is an array of dimension `(1,2)`. According to the rules of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html), the difference is a numpy array of size `(2,2)`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about "broadcasting" :)